# Intoduction to Flash and XML

Tags: xml, flash, flash-cs4

This is the first time I've used flash, and for the life of me and all my google'ing I can't seem to workout

a) How to add ActionScript

b) How to use XML (I've found tutorials but I can't seem to use them because they don't describe where to put the code.

c) What I need to do special for Flashlite (since this is for the Popcorn Hour)

It would be great if you could show me how to make links to webpages from

```
<myxml version="1">
    <links>
        <link location="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
        <link location="http://www.google.com.au">Google AU</a>
        <link location="http://www.google.se">Google SE</a>
    </links>
</myxml>
```

Just a simple example XML I made.

Also if there are any security tips for Flash I should know about that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small basic tutorial on how to load XML from Flash that you can find [here](http://adamzwakk.com/?p=24)

Answer (score 1):

Buy or find [Essential Actionscript 3.0](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948) .It will answer most of your questions and it is a great way to learn actionscript.

Comment: Any differences between AS 2 and AS 3?

Comment: Huge. But you may need to code in as2 only if you edit a older .fla file coded in as2 or if you have this requirement from an advertising agency but they get fewer by the time.

Comment: damn, because flash lite only supports AS 2

Comment: Ah I see... Well you can search for as2 to as3 migration. As a syntax is not that different but the way you think and code (OOP,Design patterns) changes a lot.

Comment: But in my opinion if you want to evolve as an actionscript programmer you must start with as3